How can I utilize Microsoft easyauth within a Django Webapp?
I am hosting a django project on Azure, and I need to utilize Microsoft's sign in for the project. I am unable to install any third party packages such as django_microsoft_auth, and so it needs to be written from scratch.
I need to be able to:

Prevent any user who is not signed in at all from accessing any of the views
have different "groups" with different access levels

I am fairly familiar with the Django user system, and so if there is a way of tapping into that, it would be very convenient, but any method which works is fine by me.
If anyone has any resources they could point me to, or similar questions it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Can you check this GitHub repo.

I tried the following Django code to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the views.
Code :
views.py :
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
import requests

ms_identity_web = settings.MS_IDENTITY_WEB
def index(request):
    return render(request, "auth/status.html")

@ms_identity_web.login_required
def token_details(request):
    return render(request, 'auth/token.html')

@ms_identity_web.login_required
def call_ms_graph(request):
    ms_identity_web.acquire_token_silently()
    graph = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
    authZ = f'Bearer {ms_identity_web.id_data._access_token}'
    results = requests.get(graph, headers={'Authorization': authZ}).json()

    if 'value' in results:
        results ['num_results'] = len(results['value'])
        results['value'] = results['value'][:5]
    return render(request, 'auth/call-graph.html', context=dict(results=results))

settings.py :
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = '=o7q14#fzv9&rfqy4ub_biym+osmoll)e2z)^*q__7ik6p&!ls'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['django-call-graph.azurewebsites.net', 'localhost', '<Azurewebapp_name>.azurewebsites.net']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Sample.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['Sample/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'Sample.context_processors.context',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Sample.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Sample/static_collected')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "Sample/static"
]

# SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

from ms_identity_web.configuration import AADConfig
from ms_identity_web import IdentityWebPython
AAD_CONFIG = AADConfig.parse_json(file_path='aad.config.json')
MS_IDENTITY_WEB = IdentityWebPython(AAD_CONFIG)
ERROR_TEMPLATE = 'auth/{}.html' 
MIDDLEWARE.append('ms_identity_web.django.middleware.MsalMiddleware')

aad.config.json :
{
    "type": {
        "client_type": "CONFIDENTIAL",
        "authority_type": "SINGLE_TENANT",
        "framework": "DJANGO"
    },
    "client": {
        "client_id": "<client_ID>",
        "client_credential": "<client_secret>",
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>"
    },
    "auth_request": {
        "redirect_uri": null,
        "scopes": [],
        "response_type": "code"
    },
    "flask": null,
    "django": {
        "id_web_configs": "MS_ID_WEB_CONFIGS",
        "auth_endpoints": {
            "prefix": "auth",
            "sign_in": "sign_in",
            "edit_profile": "edit_profile",
            "redirect": "redirect",
            "sign_out": "sign_out",
            "post_sign_out": "post_sign_out"
        }
    }
}

requirements.txt :
django
requests
git+https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-utilities@main

I added the following URLs to the Azure AD app in Authentication as shown below:
http://localhost:8000/auth/redirect
https://kamdjangoap.azurewebsites.net/auth/redirect


I executed the following commands for migration and to run the Django app:
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000


Local output :



Insert the following lines into the settings.py file before deploying the project to Azure web apps; otherwise, you may encounter an HTTP redirect error.
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

Azure web app output :


Reference :  Refer this GitHub repo for complete code.

@JohnFahey Have you tried the solution that I shared?
